# What are the best interfaces you've seen for editing date-chained sequences?

Tags: dates

I want to improve the user experience for an interface used to edit what we call a date-chained sequence (perhaps there's other jargon I'm not familiar with)

For example, an online retailer might want to plan price changes in advance - maybe an item should be $200 from today until 24-NOV-2016, $150 from 25-NOV-2016 to 27-NOV-2016, and $180 from 28-NOV-2016 onwards. There should be no gaps between the date-ranges, as then the item wouldn't have a price.

Or a more complicated example: an airline wants to adjust prices based on two dates - the date of the flight and the date the customer books. Let's say the price for an economy seat for flight AB123 on a Thursday should be $100 for journeys departing 01-FEB-2016 to 14-FEB-2016 booked between 01-JAN-2016 and 14-JAN-2016; but $150 for those booked between 15-JAN-2016 and 31-JAN-2016; while flights departing 15-FEB-2016 to 29-FEB-2016 should cost $110 if booked between 01-JAN-2016 and 31-JAN-2016. Again, there should be no gaps.

Is there a name for this sort of data / user interface?

Where can I see really good user interfaces for working with this sort  of data, especially interfaces users might already be familiar with? Or do you have any other suggestions for how I should address this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sounds like a timeline to me. There are controls available that look something like this:

[image]

or this:
[image]

**Of course yours would have time on both x and y axis!**

You could have flight timeline listed on the y axis, and then dates across the x axis, and schedule prices using the little bars.

In what I imagine, the bars would span more than one row, so I suppose it could be called a time grid rather than a time line.

Answer (score 1):

**Solution1: Graph Interface**

A chart that plots price against time is a probable solution.

> The graph here need to act as a **visual form** for the user.

Internally as the user interacts with the chart, an array of the price information can be built and sent to backend.

*This solution is suitable for longer date ranges with frequent and granular price change.*

**Solution 2: Editable Table based interface**

If you are thinking of a less fancy solution. It would be a table with columns representing date ranges and price.

*This will be best suited if the date ranges are longer and the prices variation is variation minimal.*