# Visualize Date gaps and dates overlapping

Tags: web-app, info-visualisation, dates

A part can have one successor or multiples successors.
A part can also have one predecessor or multiple predecessor

The problem we have we want to quickly be able to view which part has which successors and show if there are gaps or overlaps in the date range

The columns `Start` and `Drop` are keys which identify the sequence: the predecessor `drop key` is the same as the sucessor `start key`

[image: draft visualize date gap or overlap]

The important part ist to quickly understand

- what is wrong with the `from` and `till` dates or
- if `Start` and `Drop` do not match (not the case in the exmaple)

#### What have i done?

I looked at

- [Interface design for managing overlapping date periods](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/17947/)
- [Assigning working hours on a duty roster](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/16576)
- [What are the best interfaces you've seen for editing date-chained sequences?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/88735/)

but none did match my visualization needs.

### Questions

1. What would you change to improve visibillity / glancabillity?
2. Would reducing contrast all none relevant text help?

[Table content is on codepen.io](https://codepen.io/codemuggle/pen/dyNBWXE)

#### reduced contrast sample

[image: reduced contrast sample]

Comment: To achieve a border-color for certain table-cells see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67363336/

Answer (score 1):

Try using colour cobinations and cycling through a set of predefined colors. Alternatively try stronger border colours on various parts of the table cells to try a create a link

[image: Color cells]

[image]

Comment: Yes the colors are good and simple way. to lead the eye. 
Do you think using a color for gaps and overlaps would be helpfull? 
What do you think about https://codepen.io/codemuggle/pen/dyNBWXE?